# Getting resistance and current from resistivity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electrical-resistance

> For a cylindrical resistor of length $l$, radius $a$, resistivity $\rho=\frac{\rho_0z}{r}$, and voltage $V$, I am to find the current.

Here is what I did:

$$V=IR=I\cdot\frac{\rho l}{A}=I\cdot\frac{\rho_{0}l}{a}\cdot\frac{l}{\pi a^2}=I\cdot\frac{\rho_0l^2}{\pi a^3}\Rightarrow I=\frac{V\pi a^3}{\rho_0l^2}$$

However, the provided answer is:

$$I=\frac{4V\pi a^3}{3\rho_0l^2}$$

So I think that I am missing something integral(no pun intended) or extremely basic with this question and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your working assumes the resistivity of the material is constant, when it actually varies with r and z. You can consider the cylinder as being made of concentric cylindrical shells, each with resistance $\int_{0}^{l}\frac{{\rho}_0z}{r(2{\pi}r{\delta}r)}dz=\frac{{\rho}_0l^2}{4{\pi}r^2{\delta}r}$. As each of these shells is in parallel with each other, the effective resistance, $R_T$, can be found from $\frac{1}{R_T}=\int_{0}^{a}\frac{4{\pi}r^2dr}{{\rho}_0l^2}\\=\frac{4{\pi}a^3}{3{\rho}_0l^2}$.

Hence for $I=\frac{V}{R_T}$, $I=\frac{4V{\pi}a^3}{3{\rho}_0l^2}$ as required.

Comment: Ok, slightly stupid question, but at what point are you allowed to simply multiply be volume or area, and at what point are you required to integrate?

Comment: If the resistivity is constant, the integral will convert into a multiple anyway, so you're allowed to follow your method if your resistivity is given to be a constant. If the resistivity is a function of z or r, as in this example, you are essentially multiplying to find the resistance of individual bodies but you need to carry out integration to find the sum, i.e. the total resistance of the body. TLDR: Multiply if resistivity is constant, integrate if not.

Answer (score 0):

$\rho$ depends on $r$, the distance from the axis of the cylinder, and also on $z$, the distance along the cylinder. However, $r, z$ do not appear in your solution.

Your pun is exactly right : you are missing something integral - ie an integral, in both the $r$ and $z$ variables.